SOLVED: FUSE does not call the readdir callback I provided in fuse_operations
I've been trying to write a custom filesystem with fuse and I've run into a little problem. I noticed that ls didn't work. It always failed with an error that said Function not implemented. After using the -d flag to make fuse print debug information I realised that FUSE does not even call the readdir callback. It just says it's not implemented.
The specific line where it says readdir not implemented:
unique: 262, opcode: READDIR (28), nodeid: 1, insize: 80, pid: 4699
   unique: 262, error: -38 (Function not implemented), outsize: 16

The code itself. I would have used a pastebin but I'm not sure about the policy on pastebins here.
// mkdir cd
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 31

#include <fuse3/fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mkern_types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

#define printe(msg, ...) fprintf(stderr, msg, __VA_ARGS__)

struct file_handle
{
    m_bool avail;
    char *path;
    uint64_t ptr;
    mkern_fD dir;
};

struct file_handle *ftab;
uint64_t nEntries;
mkern_boot_block bblock;
mkern_fD_dir rootDir;
FILE *dev = NULL;
m_bool kernMod = m_false;

int brkStr(char *str, char **toks[], const char brkchr);
m_uint32 CalcC32(void *data, const m_size64 size);

int getFDInfo(mkern_fD *fdir, const char *path)
{
    char *pth = NULL;
    m_char8 *name = NULL;
    int nlev = 0;
    mkern_fD dir;
    char **dirstr = NULL;

    if (!strcmp("/", path))
    {
        memcpy(fdir, &rootDir, sizeof(dir));
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(name = calloc(bblock.blk_size_bs - sizeof(mkern_fD), sizeof(m_char8))))
        return 0;
    if (!(pth = strdup(path)))
    {
        free(name);
        return 0;
    }
    if (!(nlev = brkStr(pth, &dirstr, '/')))
        goto exit_fail;
    dir = *((mkern_fD *)&rootDir);

    for (int i = 1; i < nlev; i++)
    {
        fseek(dev, (bblock.rootDir_off_blk + ((mkern_fD_dir *)&dir)->fDirs) * bblock.blk_size_bs, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&dir, sizeof(dir), 1, dev);
        fread(name, bblock.blk_size_bs - sizeof(mkern_fD), 1, dev);

        while (1)
        {
            if (!strcmp(name, dirstr[i]))
            {
                if ((dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) == MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR && dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_VISIBLE | kernMod)
                    break;
                else if (i == nlev - 1 && dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_VISIBLE | kernMod)
                    break;

                goto exit_fail;
            }

            if (!dir.next_fileDir_blk)
                goto exit_fail;

            fseek(dev, (bblock.rootDir_off_blk + dir.next_fileDir_blk) * bblock.blk_size_bs, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&dir, sizeof(dir), 1, dev);
            fread(name, bblock.blk_size_bs - sizeof(mkern_fD), 1, dev);
        }
    }

    memcpy(fdir, &dir, sizeof(dir));
    free(name);
    free(pth);
    return 1;
exit_fail:
    free(name);
    free(pth);
    return 0;
}

m_uint64 reassignHandle(const char *path, mkern_fD dir)
{
    m_uint64 found = 0;

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < nEntries; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(path, ftab[i].path))
            return 0;

        if (ftab[i].avail && !found)
        {
            ftab[i].avail = m_false;
            ftab[i].path = path;
            ftab[i].ptr = 0;
            ftab[i].dir = dir;
            found = i;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

m_uint64 createHandle(const char *path, mkern_fD dir)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nEntries; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(path, ftab[i].path))
            return 0;
    }

    if (!(ftab = reallocarray(ftab, nEntries + 1, sizeof(struct file_handle))))
        return 0;

    ftab[nEntries].avail = m_false;
    ftab[nEntries].path = path;
    ftab[nEntries].ptr = 0;
    ftab[nEntries].dir = dir;

    nEntries++;
    return nEntries - 1;
}

int releaseHandle(struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    if (!finfo)
        return 0;

    if (finfo->fh > nEntries)
        return 0;

    ftab[finfo->fh].avail = m_true;
    return 1;
}

int getHandleFDInfo(m_uint64 fh, mkern_fD *dir)
{
    if (fh > nEntries)
        return 0;

    *dir = ftab[fh].dir;
    return 1;
}

int m_readdir(const char *path, void *private_data, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t off, struct fuse_file_info *finfo, enum fuse_readdir_flags flgs)
{
    mkern_fD dir;
    char name[960];
    struct stat sinf;

    printf("what's going on\n");

    if (!finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if ((dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) != MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR)
        return -EACCES;

    if (!getHandleFDInfo(finfo->fh, &dir))
        return -EBADF;

    fseek(dev, (bblock.rootDir_off_blk + ((mkern_fD_dir *)&dir)->fDirs) * bblock.blk_size_bs, SEEK_SET);
    memset(&sinf, 0, sizeof(sinf));

    while (1)
    {
        fread(&dir, sizeof(dir), 1, dev);

        if (!(dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_VISIBLE) && !kernMod)
            goto get_next_blk;

        fread(name, sizeof(name), 1, dev);
        sinf.st_uid = getuid();
        sinf.st_gid = getgid();
        sinf.st_atime = dir.lastAcc_time;
        sinf.st_mtime = dir.lastAcc_time;

        if ((dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) == MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR)
        {
            if (!strcmp("/", path))
                sinf.st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;

            sinf.st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0644;
        }
        else
        {
            sinf.st_mode = S_IFREG | 0644;
            sinf.st_size = ((mkern_fD_file *)&dir)->size_blk * 1024;
        }

        filler(private_data, name, &sinf, 0, flgs);

    get_next_blk:
        if (!dir.next_fileDir_blk)
            break;

        fseek(dev, (bblock.rootDir_off_blk + dir.next_fileDir_blk) * bblock.blk_size_bs, SEEK_SET);
    }

    return 0;
}

int m_read(const char *path, char *data, size_t size, off_t off, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    printf("as\n");
    strcpy(data, "Yeah whatever rocks your boat\n");
    return sizeof("Yeah whatever rocks your boat\n");
}

int m_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *st, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    mkern_fD inf;

    if (!path || !st)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!getFDInfo(&inf, path))
        return -ENOENT;

    memset(st, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    st->st_uid = getuid();
    st->st_gid = getgid();
    st->st_atime = inf.lastAcc_time;
    st->st_mtime = inf.lastAcc_time;

    if ((inf.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) == MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR)
    {
        if (!strcmp("/", path))
            st->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0755;

        st->st_mode = S_IFDIR | 0644;
    }
    else
    {
        st->st_mode = S_IFREG | 0644;
        st->st_size = ((mkern_fD_file *)&inf)->size_blk * 1024;
    }

    return 0;
}

int m_create(const char *path, mode_t mode, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    char **dirstr = NULL;
    mkern_fD dir;

    if (!path || !finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (getFDInfo(&dir, path))
        return EEXIST;

    if (!(finfo->fh = reassignHandle(path, dir)))
    {
        if (!(finfo->fh = createHandle(path, dir)))
            return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

int m_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    mkern_fD dir;

    if (!path || !finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (finfo->flags & O_CREAT)
        printe("can't use open to create\n", NULL);

    if (!getFDInfo(&dir, path))
        return -ENOENT;

    if ((dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) == MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR && (finfo->flags & O_ACCMODE) != O_RDONLY)
        return -EACCES;

    if (!(finfo->fh = reassignHandle(path, dir)))
    {
        if (!(finfo->fh = createHandle(path, dir)))
            return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

int m_release(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    if (!path || !finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!releaseHandle(finfo))
        return -ENOENT;

    return 0;
}

int m_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    return 0;
}

int m_opendir(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    mkern_fD dir;

    if (!path || !finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!getFDInfo(&dir, path))
        return -ENOENT;

    if ((dir.type & MKERN_FDIR_TYPE) != MKERN_FDIR_TYPE_DIR)
        return -EACCES;

    if (!(finfo->fh = reassignHandle(path, dir)))
    {
        if (!(finfo->fh = createHandle(path, dir)))
            return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

int m_releasedir(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *finfo)
{
    if (!path || !finfo)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (!releaseHandle(finfo))
        return -ENOENT;

    return 0;
}

void *m_init()
{
    return NULL;
}

struct fuse_operations fo = {
    .open = m_open,
    .release = m_release,
    .readdir = m_readdir,
    .read = m_read,
    .getattr = m_getattr,
    .create = m_create,
    .opendir = m_opendir,
    .releasedir = m_releasedir,
    .mkdir = m_mkdir,
    .init = m_init,
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *args[6];
    mkern_fD atab;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printe("msh: incorrect usage\n", NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(dev = fopen(argv[1], "r+")))
    {
        printe("could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    fread(&bblock, sizeof(bblock), 1, dev);
    fseek(dev, bblock.rootDir_off_blk * bblock.blk_size_bs, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&rootDir, sizeof(rootDir), 1, dev);

    ftab = calloc(4, sizeof(struct file_handle));
    kernMod = m_true;
    if (!getFDInfo(&atab, "/allocTab"))
    {
        printe("something is wrong\n", NULL);
        return -1;
    }
    kernMod = m_false;

    ftab[3].dir = atab;
    ftab[3].path = "/allocTab";
    nEntries = 4;

    if (bblock.checksum != CalcC32(&bblock, sizeof(bblock) - 4))
    {
        printe("boot block corrupted\n", NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    args[0] = argv[0];
    args[1] = "-f";
    args[2] = argv[2];
    args[3] = "-d";
    args[4] = "-oauto_unmount";
    args[5] = "-s";

    return fuse_main_real(6, args, &fo, sizeof(fo), NULL);
}

m_uint32 CalcC32(void *data, const m_size64 size)
{
    m_uint32 b, crc = 0xffffffff, mask;
    m_byte *bs = (m_byte *)data;

    for (m_size64 i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        b = bs[i];
        crc ^= b;
        for (m_size64 j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            mask = -(crc & 1);
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xedb88320 & mask);
        }
    }

    return ~crc;
}

int brkStr(char *str, char **toks[], const char brkchr)
{
    char **tmp = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    if (!(str && toks && brkchr))
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if (!tmp || !tmp[n])
        {
            tmp = reallocarray(tmp, n + 2, sizeof(char *));
            tmp[n] = &str[i];
            tmp[n + 1] = NULL;
        }

        if (str[i] == brkchr)
        {
            str[i] = 0;
            n++;
        }
        else if (!str[i])
        {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }

    *toks = tmp;
    return n;
}

I expect that the m_readdir function be called, but I suspect there's something I'm not doing.
Well, this is embarrassing. Turns out that the reason everything was going haywire was because I used pkg-config fuse --libs --cflags when compiling instead of pkg-config fuse3 --libs --cflags. I think this should serve as a deterrent to me to include the compilation command I used next time.

What's making you sure that it is readdir that it claims isn't implemented, as opposed to some other fuse_operations entry that FUSE attempts to call first?

That's the problem here. FUSE lacks so much in formal documentation that I'm not even sure of that. So maybe someone who has experience with FUSE can tell me what I'm not getting right.

Looking at the source, it does seem like it should be calling pretty directly into readdir. One note, why are you calling fuse_main_real instead of fuse_main? What you show should do the same as the fuse_main macro, but the docs do tell you not to do it. Beyond that, have you tried using a debugger to see what's happening? This is a fairly simple program, so it shouldn't be too hard to see what the operations structure looks like at the point it's being checked.

I thought using real would somehow solve my problems

You may get away with calling fuse_main_real directly for now, but not in a future release. The current development version has an extra parameter.

I know it's outdated, but what is going on? Why isn't my m_readdir recognised?
